# The right way to encrypt sensitive data with an user password

Tags: hash, symmetric, key-derivation

I am developing something like 1Password and I want to be sure that method that I use is secure. Main idea of the app is storing user passwords, and is protected with a global master password. Main scope of this post is to be sure that algorithms and logic will protect user's sensitive data from brute force, rainbow table attacks, even with special ASIC hardware

### Algorithm

**All generated data are using secure random [generating_random_data](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/generating_random_data/)

#### Creation

1. User define a `Master Password`
2. I generate random `Master Key`, secret high entropy key
3. I generate random `Master Salt`, this is not secret and will be appended to final public binary
4. Derive using `Argon2id` from `Master Password` and `Master Salt`, 96 bytes

   - 32 bytes `Derived Key`
   - 32 bytes `Derived Hash`
   - 32 bytes `Derived Salt`
5. Hash using `Blake2b` from `Derived Hash` and `Derived Salt` and name result `Pre Hash`
6. Hash using `Blake2b` from `Pre Hash` and name result `Public Hash`, this hash is not secret and will be appended to final binary file
7. Encrypt using `Authenticated encryption` `XChaCha20Poly1305Ietf` -> `Master Key`, with previously `Derived Key` and name result as `Public Encrypted Master Key`
8. Save into a `Public` binary file `Master Salt`, `Public Hash`, `Public Encrypted Master Key`

#### Opening

1. Read `Master Password` from user's input
2. Read `Master Salt` from user's `Public` binary
3. Derive using `Argon2id` from `Master Password` and `Master Salt`, 96 bytes

   - 32 bytes `Derived Key`
   - 32 bytes `Derived Hash`
   - 32 bytes `Derived Salt`
4. Hash using `Blake2b` from `Derived Hash` and `Derived Salt` and name result `Pre Hash`
5. Hash using `Blake2b` from `Pre Hash` and name result `Public Hash`
6. Compare `Public Hash` from step `6` with saved in `Public` binary `Public Hash` that was previously saved in step `8` when created
7. If `NOT equal` throw `invalidPasswordOrCorruptedData`
8. If `equal` Decrypt using `Authenticated encryption` `XChaCha20Poly1305Ietf` -> `Public Encrypted Master Key` with previously `Derived Key` from step `4` and name result as `Master Key`
9. Use `Master Key` to encrypt and decrypt user's sensitive data

#### Summary

From above logic it is clear that we encrypt `Master Key` with derived data from user's password and then use that `Master Key` to encrypt all other sensitive data

#### Questions

1. Is this logic enough for protecting user's secrets ?
2. Will it protect from brute force, rainbow table attacks ?
3. Are there any steps that must be eliminated or useless ?

#### Remarks

I am using [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium), [swift-sodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium) for all crypto operations, and follow `libsodium`'s best practice and suggestions

By default I am using `10` iterations and `64M` of RAM for `argon2id`

Comment: Why are you _developing something like 1Password_? Why not help develop 1Password (or similar)?

Comment: @user2768 I see the biggest problem with 1Password is the subscription model. While on the surface this sounds good there is a limit of how many subscription models I can handle, the minimum for 1Password is $36 or $60/yr and I must use their server. I am currently grandfathered in but that may change in the future.  The problem I have with umbri is security experience, it must be secure and that is not easy. An alternative must have starting power and support.

Comment: @zaph The subscription model is certainly an issue for some (typically online) password managers, but some (typically offline) password managers do not suffer from this, e.g., KeePass, Roboform, Password Safe, ... (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_password_managers for a long list of password managers.)

Comment: @user2768 I think that Password Manager must be open source and open for code review, and not a black box, that somehow is working

Comment: @user2768 I agree that there are multiple alternatives but from my point of view, there are many aspects that can be improved

Comment: @umbri Many password managers are open source and can be reviewed. Some aspects of such password managers can no doubt be improved, but this doesn't necessitate an entirely new password manager, it suffices to identify issues and fix them. Hence, your efforts might be better placed on an existing open source project, rather than a new project.

Comment: Beyond security there is concern about long term viability and UI, I would want something approaching 1Password. That is a big challenge. WRT security I would want to know experience and credentials.